# ovirt vdsm vlan - cant create virtual lan only wan port

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, fedora, vlan, ovirt

I installed ovirt 3.3 on fedora 19 on my server.

The Server has one ethernet connection, and it is a WAN so I don't have a LAN ip, or DHCP.

I set a bridged interface (ovirtmgmt) on this interface with my wan ip of `80.72.37.34` and my gateway of `80.72.37.33`.

Now I have all set on one server with fedora and I try to create virtual machine, everything looks fine but i don't have idea how to configure network on guest system.

Before ovirt I used kvm and created network by virsh, it was working like a charm and have build in dhcp server.

Now I just want to have virtual network like `192.168.1.*` on my guests systems with internet access, try to do that for 3 days without any result.

Google wasn't any help. In the administrator panel in host configuration I have one network interface and one logical ovirtmgmt with my static address no idea how to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

Since you created a bridge, that means any VM attached to the ovirtmgmt network will be able to use IPs from the WAN subnet. What you describe doing with libvirt is a NAT network.
I would personally just install a router on the WAN address, and place my oVirt hosts behind it, for ease of management, that way the hosts and VMs will be on the ovirtmgmt network, that would belong to your private IP subnet and there you can run as many VMs with as many addresses as you like. The entire network will be using the router to access the internet of course.

EDIT: if all you have is one host, you can set up iptables for routing on it, set up a second network for VMs only, and use the private subnet on it.

Comment: thank You very much for help, when You say router you mean phisical device or can I do it somehow in linux?

*" if all you have is one host, you can set up iptables for routing on it, set up a second network for VMs only, and use the private subnet on it."*

great idea but i dont know how to do it :( ..what am I saying.I dont even know where to start, but it sound like great idea :)

Comment: well, if you don't know how to set up a linux box as a router, I would definitely recommend you just get a small off the shelf router, depending on your budget and the DC where you are hosted policy. One that supports dd-wrt would be perfect